# React Native: Strange Issue With Updating State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using the code below:

```
makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    let items = []; 
    models.forEach(element => {  //models is an array of the list of models
        this.pushReports(element, items); 
    });
    console.log("This is the item array: ",items); 
    this.setState({
        data:items
    });
    console.log("This is the data in state: ",this.state.data); 
}
```

Somehow, the console log for the items array is showing me the array that I need, but the console log for the this.state.data is empty. How can this be possible? The log for the items array is run right *before* state is set.

This is preventing me from updating my state.

Comment: it miss the pushReports method. If you need a new array why do not use array.map ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how it can miss the pushReports method but still be logged as expected in the console.log("This is the item array: ", items); line?

Comment: Miss in question, not in data flow!

Comment: setState is ASYNC if you want to log it you have to do it in a callback this.setState({myAttr: myVal}, () => console.log(this.state.myVal));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState` is rendering asynchronously. And you're trying to print in next line so it will not give immediate results as you want.

Solution: do this in next line,

`setTimeout(() => {console.log("This is the data in state: ",this.state.data) }, 1000)`

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState()` does not run synchronously. Your state is not guaranteed to be updated on the next immediate line, but it will be updated properly on the next render cycle. Try putting console.log within `render()` and you'll see.

Discussion about this topic here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710

Answer (score 1):

Since `setState` works in an asynchronous way. That means after calling `setState` the `this.state` is not immediately changed. So if you want to perform an action immediately after setting state, use 2nd argument as callback on `setState`. Consider this example:

```
this.setState({
    data: newData
}, () => {
  //TODO: Do something with this.state here
});
```